# Normalized and unnormalized steepest descent using exact line search

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, machine-learning

"When exact line search is used, scale factors in the descent direction have no effect-so normalized or unnormalized direction can be used"

Please explain this.To my understanding 
[image: Exact line search]

Also this is the definition for 1

[image: Normalized steepest descent]

And this is the definition for 2
 [image: Unnormalized steepest descent]

So once the value of v[nu] is chosen nsd is fixed and unsd is some different value so value of t should be different

Comment: Let $\Delta x$, $\Delta y$ be two search directions satisfying $\Delta x = 2 \Delta y$. Feed both into the exact line search algorithm to get step sizes $t_x$, $t_y$, respectively. Then it should be evident that $t_x=t_y/2$, and that $t_x \Delta x = t_y \Delta y$. So it didn't really matter which of the two directions you started with, you're going to end up in the same place after exact line search.

Comment: Thanks a lot..understood it